# google-services.json Google Cloud oauth login and Firebase dynamic link same project android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have an Android project where I am using Google Cloud authentication service, where I downloaded the google-services.json file and everything is working.

Now that using Firebase's Dynamic Link service, where it asks to download another google-services.json file and put it in the same location.

I don't know how to proceed in this case, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same project then feel free to use the last one `google-services.json` that it suggests downloading because it will already include your previous configuration.
You can easily check this if you compare the first and second one jsons.

Make sure that you only have this most recent downloaded config file in your app.

You can get the most recent config file for your Android app in [Firebase Console](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#android&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) at any moment.

1. Go to your [Project settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general) in the Firebase console.
2. In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app for which you need a config file.
3. Click `google-services.json`.