# Google-Json file from mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-json-api

I am trying to run my project after connecting it to mongoDb but I recieve an error saying: "File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. ". Before when I used firebase, there was an easy way to get this google-json file but how can it be done with using mongoDb? Thanks!

Comment: There `google-services.json` file is used to configure your app to use firebase right? Are you attempting to use firebase services currently? It doesn't sound like it. If you are then it sounds like you can grab it from the firebase console. If not, which seems to be the case, then I don't think you need that file and you may just need to remove some old config/setting that's making the code look for it?

Comment: Actually it seems to be necessary to use it when implementing one tap google sign in feature! I actually took it from firebase now but I find it odd that it cant be found 
 on mongoDb site when they have google sign-in feature, same as firebase. @user20042973

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a Google feature. The config file instructs the app on how to communicate with Google for your project/app. Why would MongoDB know or have that information? Also seems like this isn't necessarily specific to firebase according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334801/google-services-json-google-cloud-oauth-login-and-firebase-dynamic-link-same-pro)

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right regarding that but wish it was more easily accessible since the only method to obtain it, that I know of, is from creating a firebase project @user20042973